# Set up of conditional redirect in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, .htaccess

I've asked a question over at Stackoverflow thinking that it wasn't really EE related

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229829/set-up-of-conditional-redirect-in-htaccess

But now I'm not so sure that the rules I'm using to remove index.php aren't having an effect.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your final answer here for people to see without having to link?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I eventually went with;

```
# Rewrite for new language based urls
# This is to try and get all current pages going to /en/(old url) with a 301 redirect
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|en)(/.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]

# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I'm sure that could be refined a fair bit as there is some duplication but it works so I'm happy with it for now as it is a temporary requirement.

Comment: Did you ever refine this at all?